# Does there exist a way to do an equality check on 2 public keys in anchor tests with chai?

Tags: anchor

When I compare two public keys with:

```
expect(lotteryState.authority).to.equal(user.publicKey);
```

I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: expected PublicKey(DCpJReAfonSrgohiQbTmKKbjbqVofspFRHz9yQikzooP){ _bn: <BN: b5531d6246f2015e72621c71ebf9304871dd8bbcf6f6c714948be6ddbd1e6ff2> } to equal PublicKey(DCpJReAfonSrgohiQbTmKKbjbqVofspFRHz9yQikzooP){ _bn: <BN: b5531d6246f2015e72621c71ebf9304871dd8bbcf6f6c714948be6ddbd1e6ff2> }
```

As you can see, both keys are the same but the test suite says that they are different. I can fix this by changing to a deep equality check:

```
expect(lotteryState.authority).to.deep.equal(user.publicKey);
```

But I am wondering if there exists a native method in anchor to compare to keys such as:

```
expect(lotteryState.authority).to.publicKeyEqual(user.publicKey);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PublicKey class contains an `equals` [method](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#equals) that can compare two pubkeys:

```
  equals(publicKey: PublicKey): boolean {
    return this._bn.eq(publicKey._bn);
  }
```

IIRC there can also be compare issues here as well, so it is pretty common to just compare the base58 strings of both pubkeys (`pubkey1.toBase58()` and `pubkey2.toBase58()`).